# Am I getting the right path in Magento?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, magento

I am willing to include/require a file in DATA.php in magento.
i have the code

```
    public function formatPrice($price)
    {
require_once(Mage::getBaseDir('app').'\design\frontend\neighborhood\default\template\catalog\product\view.‌​phtml');

    echo $Abowl;
     }
```

But It doesn't seem like they are working, since when you use require the execution will be stop if can't read the file.

My question is how to get the full path and print the full path out to debugged

**UPDATE 1**
I tried to apply the die() function into my function like this :

```
  public function formatPrice($price)
{
    die( 'here!' );
    require_once(Mage::getBaseDir('app').'/design/frontend/neighborhood/default/template/catalog/product/view.‌​phtml');
    echo $price;
}
```

But It bring error still and gives result as the image shows below:
ps:the path i found in Linux : */var/www/html/app/design/frontend/neighborhood/default/template/catalog/category*

[image]

By the way I have an additional question about how to get access to the $price?

Comment: You should remove your customizations, turn on template hints in the admin and find the template that renders the price, copy the template as an override and customize the price there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your error logs if they are enabled:

> root/var/log/exception.log
>   root/var/log/system.log

And apache logs.

On to your question require once will break if it cannot find the file so your issue is that it doesn't get called. Place a die at the top of the function to ensure you can get inside:

```
    public function formatPrice($price)
    {
die( 'here!' );
require_once(Mage::getBaseDir('app').'\design\frontend\neighborhood\default\template\catalog\product\view.‌​phtml');

    echo $Abowl;
     }
```

To output the file path run this:

```
var_dump( Mage::getBaseDir('app').'\design\frontend\neighborhood\default\template\catalog\product\view.‌​phtml' );
die;
```

Comment: Still not working right. I have updated my question please have a look, thanks :)

Comment: Can you post your current result using vanilla $price and your desired result after you reformat the $price to suit your needs?

Comment: Don't worry about this question, I found out that this can't satisfy my require.